# jquery defaultDate not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

The problem I have is the following:
I would like to get the Text from

```
<div id="article-pubdate">2013-07-27</div>
```

as a defaultDate into

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker'>
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1990:2013',
  });

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", new Date($("#article-pubdate").text().replace(/\-/g, ',')));

});
```

setDate works, but doesn't let me edit the date afterwards, it always submits the date that is in #article-pubdate, so that is not an option:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '1990:2013',
      });

   $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date($("#article-pubdate").text().replace(/\-/g, ',')));

    });
```

Can you guys tell me what's going on?

Comment: The date is in a different format. Have you tried to configure the datepicker like this: `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"`?

Comment: I just tried, and it didn't change anything, no :(  
Also: where is the date in a different format? The `new Date` part is exactly the same and the `#article-pubdate` also didn't change...

Comment: I've tried your code and i can change date in the datepicker with no problem. Although, if you want to change year, you have to first pick year and then click on any day in the datepicker. Here's your code in JSFiddle: [JSFiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/cWy8X/)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/yTShq/)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $("#article-pubdate").text());
```